# NodeJS: ASync / callback problems

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm working on the NodeJS framework, where the sql is executed after the main body.

I have used the basic sql connection block and am not sure how to integrate async or callbacks in the block.

My code is below:

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');
 var pool = mysql.createPool({
     connectionLimit: 100,
     host: "localhost",
     user: "...user...",
     password: "...pw...",
     database: "...db..."
  });
```

...
...
...

```
  app.get('/*', function(req, res) {


  var sql = mysql.format("SELECT * FROM test_rest WHERE location=? LIMIT 2", [user_input]);


  pool.getConnection(function(err,connection) {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
            connection.release();
            if (err) throw err;


         });
  });


 var jsonResponse = [];
 var obj = {};
 obj["text"] = 'hi this is' + user_nsew_1;

 jsonResponse.push(obj);
 res.send(jsonResponse);
 });
```

Comment: Please understand that `if (err) throw err` in async callbacks is not useful error handling and will come back to bite you.  You're in a response handler.  You can do a `res.status(500).send(something); return;` rather than punting on actual error handling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the response INSIDE the inner callback as that is the only place that the data is available:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {

    var sql = mysql.format("SELECT * FROM test_rest WHERE location=? LIMIT 2", [user_input]);

    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send("could not get database connection");
            return;
        }
        connection.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
            connection.release();
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send("database query failed");
                return;
            }
            var jsonResponse = [];
            var obj = {};
            obj["text"] = 'hi this is' + user_nsew_1;

            jsonResponse.push(obj);
            res.send(jsonResponse);
         });
     });
 });
```

Also, since it looks like you plan on incorporating user input into your sql query, be careful that the input is sanitized appropriately so you are not vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make sure that the MySQL library you are using either supports Promise . Which are required by `await` and `async` .You can use  [Bluebird's](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) promisifyAll to wrap the library. or you can encapsulate the mysql library with promise.

For example `async-db.js`:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const pool = mysql.createPool({
   connectionLimit: 100,
   host: "localhost",
   user: "...user...",
   password: "...pw...",
   database: "...db..."
});
let query = function( sql, values ) {
   return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
     pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
          reject( err )
        } else {
          connection.query(sql, values, ( err, rows) => {
              if ( err ) {
                 reject( err );
              } else {
                 resolve(rows);
              }
              connection.release();
          });
       }
     });
   });
}

module.exports = { query }
```

Usage`test.js`:

```
const { query } = require('./async-db')
async function selectAllData( ) {
  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM my_table'
  let dataList = await query( sql )
  return dataList
}

async function getData() {
  let dataList = await selectAllData()
  console.log( dataList )
}

getData()
```